# Populate the HashSet by reading it from the property file

Tags: java, properties

Below is my `config.property file`

```
TABLES: table1 table2

#For Table1
table1.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/garden
table1.user: gardener
table1.password: shavel
table1.driver: jdbc-driver
table1.percentage: 80
table1.column: column1
table1.column: column2
table1.column: column3



#For Table2
table2.url: jdbc:mysql://otherhost:3306/forest
table2.user: forester
table2.password: axe
table2.driver: jdbc-driver
table2.percentage: 20
table2.column: column1
table2.column: column2
table2.column: column3
```

Below is my code in which I am trying to read above property file and make `ReadTableConnectionInfo` object by populating it with different values but somehow columns HashSet is not getting populated with all the columns name corresponding to each table. I only see one column name in each `columns HashSet` for each table.

```
private static void readPropertyFile() throws IOException {

    prop.load(Read.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

    tableNames = Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty("TABLES").split(" "));

    for (String arg : tableNames) {

        ReadTableConnectionInfo ci = new ReadTableConnectionInfo();

        String url = prop.getProperty(arg + ".url");
        String user = prop.getProperty(arg + ".user");
        String password = prop.getProperty(arg + ".password");
        String driver = prop.getProperty(arg + ".driver");
        String table = prop.getProperty(arg + ".table");
        double percentage = Double.parseDouble(prop.getProperty(arg + ".percentage"));

        String columnPrefix = arg + ".column";
        HashSet<String> columns = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String key : prop.stringPropertyNames()) {
            if (key.startsWith(columnPrefix))
                columns.add(prop.getProperty(key));
        }

        ci.setUrl(url);
        ci.setUser(user);
        ci.setPassword(password);
        ci.setDriver(driver);
        ci.setTableName(table);
        ci.setPercentage(percentage);
        ci.setColumns(columns);

        tableList.put(arg, ci);
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here in populating columns HashSet and then adding that columns HashSet to `ReadTableConnectionInfo class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're repeating the same key more than once in your properties file, so when loading it only one key gets loaded in the `Properties` object:

```
table1.column: column1
table1.column: column2 //key: table1.column
table1.column: column3 //key: table1.column
//similar for table2
```

Just change your key name to something else.

If you don't want to do that, you can concatenate all the values in a single key and then use `String#split` function to recover every value.